# CKEditor : how to ensure consistency for inputs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKeditor in my site to get user inputs. I'm using CKEditor as I want user to be able to do some kind of formatting say making text bold, italics, ability to copy-paste content etc. 
The input that I get are also used to make some reports.

Now I'm facing the issue that some users are different fonts [some use Arial, some Calibiri, etc] and also use the font size of their preference.

When making reports I want to ensure consistency with respect to at least two things for text entered through site - Font and font size [say I want it to be restricted to Arial and size 10].

I was thinking to disable CKEditor features for selecting font and font size. But if the user is copy-pasting the content then I'll still have the issue of font and size. I'm looking for options that I can try .

One option that came to my mind is - after pasting the content, if I can run the CKEditor with some option to replace the content as per my specification of font & size. If so, how can I do this?

Another option that I'm thinking is - to have another field in the form, that will take the input from the field entered by user and set the value using CKEditor as per my specification.

In both cases, I need to know when the user has completed his action on the field for me to update either the same or different field. 
Any suggestions?

thanks
pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way to do this is simply to call `selectAll` and `removeFormat` commands on `getData` event:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        getData: function() {
            // Save the old selection
            var ranges = this.getSelection().getRanges();

            this.execCommand( 'selectAll' );
            this.execCommand( 'removeFormat' );

            // Restore the selection
            this.getSelection().selectRanges( ranges );
        }
    }
});
```

You can also do this on `paste` event if you like. Please note that `removeFormat` can destroy your selection and editor won't be able to restore it.

This is a dirty way but you can easily [change tags](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.removeFormatTags) and [attributes](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.removeFormatAttributes) you want to remove. You can also use this one: `config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;` to "dehtmllize" pasted content.

However, to do this gently, you should read a little bit about [the data processor](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor).

---

The gentle approach is:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
                attributes: {
                    style: function( attribute ) {
                        return false;
                    },
                    width: function( attribute ) {
                        return false;
                    },
                    height: function( attribute ) {
                        return false;
                    },
                    // ...
                    // You can modify (remove) any attribute you want
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Eventually you can even filter the `style` attribute with regex and remove some bits that you don't like.

Comment: Took some time to read through the documents related to Data processor. I will take the second approach to progress.